# Contribution Invoice - renamed Title

Tags: message-templates, system

I renamed the Message Title of my Contribution-invoice message template.  It's no longer in my list of system workflow templates.  Does anyone know how I can find it in order to put the message title back to what it should be?

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All solved - I had changed the Title to VAT Invoice so it was down at the bottom of the list Doh!  thank you anyway